# "android:theme" attribute ignore gravity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-styles

There is my `app_style.xml`

```
<style name="EditText.LargePassword" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:imeOptions">flagNoExtractUi</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">numberPassword</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">56sp</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

And part of layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/giant_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/giant_margin"
    android:theme="@style/EditText.LargePassword"
    tools:text="12345"
    tools:ignore="TextFields"
    />
```

As you can see, I apply `EditText.LargePassword` style via `android:theme` attribute:

[image: via android:theme]

There is a problem: every attribute applied, except `android:gravity`.

Okay, let's try with `style` attribute:

```
style="@style/EditText.LargePassword"
```

Boom! Indicator and cursor are gone:

[image]

But now `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` works.

As I read, `style` *==* `theme`, but `style` don't apply to children of `View`. Are there any differences? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Styles and Themes whilst similar are not exactly the same.  A style applies only to one specific view whereas a theme will apply to a View/ViewGroup/Activity and all of its children.

In your case you are actually mixing attributes from both styles and themes into one setting which is why it's not working properly.  To get both you will need to take the three colorControl attributes and define them as a theme:

```
<style name="LargePasswordTheme" >
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

The rest can stay as a style.  Then you can add both this and your style to the EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/giant_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/giant_margin"
    android:theme="@style/LargePasswordTheme"
    android:style="@style/EditText.LargePassword"
    tools:text="12345"
    tools:ignore="TextFields"
    />
```

Further reading with good explanations can be found [here](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/11/19/styles-on-android/) and [here](https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/).